# Using the expression builder in the Atlas function in QGIS to group features?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I am trying to show only record in the atlas for the following attribute table...

```
ogc_fid | id |     phasename       | exampleinfo
----------------------------------------------------------
   2    | 0  | 1- 3 Lower Hillgate | example information 1
   2    | 0  | 1- 3 Lower Hillgate | example information 2
   2    | 0  | 1- 3 Lower Hillgate | example information 3
   2    | 0  | 1- 3 Lower Hillgate | example information 4
   2    | 0  | 5 Lower Hillgate    | example information 1
   2    | 0  | 5 Lower Hillgate    | example information 2
   2    | 0  | 5 Lower Hillgate    | example information 3
   2    | 0  | 3 Lower Hillgate    | example information 1
```

So in my atlas I only want their to be 3 records.

Is their a simpler way to do this as opposed to making a copy of the data and having to then use the combined data to make an atlas?

The reason why I am doing this is because the example information is different and i want to show the attribute table data associated to the `phasename`in an attribute table shown below the atlas map window I am trying to create.